# Receiving googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: 403 despite being calendar owner and/or writer

Tags: google-calendar-api

I followed the [Google Calendar Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) and my python script can read calendars. But after following the guide for [creating new events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events), my script gets an "Insufficient Permission" error. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but this is a google apps for business account, so all addresses & ids are '@mybusiness.com', not '@gmail.com'

I'm trying to figure out where I've gone wrong. Any help would be appreciated

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

import datetime

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/calendar-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Python Quickstart'
CALENDARID='redacted@redacted.com'
service=None

def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, 'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def read_calendar():
    CAL=service.calendarList().get(calendarId=CALENDARID).execute()
    print("Calendar Summary & Role:",CAL['summary'],CAL['accessRole'])


def insert_event():

    event = {
      'summary': 'Test Insert Event',
      'location': 'Home',
      'description': 'Automagic for the people',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2016-05-29T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2016-05-29T10:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      },
      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': True,
      },
    }

    event = service.events().insert(calendarId=CALENDARID, body=event).execute()
    print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))

def main():
    global service
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.

    Creates a Google Calendar API service object and outputs a list of the next
    10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    eventsResult = service.events().list(
        calendarId=CALENDARID, timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))

        print(start,end,'Summary Redacted')
        print("----------\n")

    read_calendar()
    insert_event()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my output, minus the list of 10 events

```
$ ./gcal.py
Getting the upcoming 10 events
2016-06-29T09:00:00-04:00 2016-06-29T10:00:00-04:00 Summary Redacted
----------

<..etc... for 10 events, then -->

Calendar Summary & Role: redacted@redacted.com owner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gcal.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "./gcal.py", line 110, in main
    insert_event()
  File "./gcal.py", line 79, in insert_event
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId=CALENDARID, body=event).execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 760, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/redacted%40redacted.com/events?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

Comment: Check this SO question [Why is Google Calendar API (oauth2) responding with 'Insufficient Permission'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970917/why-is-google-calendar-api-oauth2-responding-with-insufficient-permission) and [google plus api: “insufficientPermissions” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978192/google-plus-api-insufficientpermissions-error) for more information.