# Why is there a "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" when the request event google calendar?

Tags: php, android, google-calendar-api

On the client(android) get AuthCode and sent to the server where you want to use the calendar, get the token but when query the event an error occurs?

```
Google_Service_Exception
{
    "error": {
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
    }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to the [*on topic* / *off topic* border of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (I think it *on*-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an authorization problem, so I suggest going through the authorization process again to generate a fresh access/refresh token pair, paying close attention to the Google account you're authorizing and the scopes requested.

[This link will give you the information about API Errors](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970917/why-is-google-calendar-api-oauth2-responding-with-insufficient-permission). Try to revoke the access to the app at https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens. Despite having the scope in the list, and the scope showing up on Google's OAuth2 grant page, the additional scope wasn't granted.

Also, from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-doubleclick-for-advertisers-api/nhUOWqV_GJ4), this might be an authorization problem, rather than a problem with permissions. Suggested action is going through the authorization process again to generate a fresh access/refresh token pair, paying close attention to the Google account you're authorizing and the scopes requested.